# Get last datetime from from weekday() index in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get the most recent `datetime` of a `weekday()` index in Python. How could I do this?

**Example:**
Let's say today is Wednesday 02/09 (`weekday` index 2). Input `0` would give me `datetime` of last Tuesday, which is 02/07. `3` would give me `datetime` of last Thursday, which would be 02/03.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke it down to small steps, of course you can combine them to fewer expressions:

```
from datetime import date

def most_recent_date(most_recent_index):
    today = date.today()
    today_index = today.weekday()
    today_ordinal = today.toordinal()
    most_recent_ordinal = today_ordinal - (today_index - most_recent_index) % 7
    most_recent = date.fromordinal(most_recent_ordinal)
    return most_recent

print(most_recent_date(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, `weekday()` only gives n'th day of the week based on a time instance.
So, ideally, the best way to get most recent weekday would be `date.today().weekday()`.